# Taking a form response, making an api call then displaying the api call in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to have a Django form capture data from a user's input, take the input to make an API call to [Aylien API](https://aylien.com/) and display the raw json result on the same page.

I'm able to take the form input and successfully make an API call & get the JSON to print on the console, but am having a hard time displaying the call's result on the page.

I keep getting **UnboundLocalError: local variable 'api_response' referenced before assignment** error. Code below

**models.py**

```py
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class News(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField(max_length=120)
```

**form.py**

```py
from django import forms
from .models import News

class NewsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = News
        fields = [
            'title']
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import News
from .form import NewsForm
import requests
import aylien_news_api
from aylien_news_api.rest import ApiException

def news_create_view(request):
    ## link form to model for gathering search term from user
    form = NewsForm(request.POST)

    if form.is_valid():
        # create an instance of the aylien api class
        api_instance = aylien_news_api.DefaultApi()

        ## build opts for api call from the response from the user
        opts = {
            'title': form.cleaned_data['title'],
            'language': ['en'],
            'not_language': ['es', 'it'],
            'published_at_start': 'NOW-7DAYS',
            'published_at_end': 'NOW'
        }
        try: 
            # List the stories
            api_response = api_instance.list_stories(**opts)
        except ApiException as e:
            print("Exception when calling DefaultApi->list_stories: %s\n" % e)

        ## re-instantiate the form and save to admin    
        form.save()
        form = NewsForm()

    else:
        form = NewsForm()

    ## context for models
    context = {
        'form': form,
        'api_response': api_response
    }

    ## render pages in Django dynamically (static HTML is slow to load)
    return render(request, "news/show_result.html", context)
```

**show_result.html**

```html
<div class="row">
    <form method="GET"> {% csrf_token %}
        <!-- the 'as_p' method turns the django-rendered form into html for the user -->
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit", value="Search" />

    </form>

</div>
<div class="row"> 
    {{ api_response }}
</div>
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong here, just can't seem to figure out what

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this error because your form is invalidated, and `api_response` will only be defined if the form is valid.

To fix your problem, Change this:

```
form = NewsForm(request.POST)
```

To this:

```
form = NewsForm(request.POST or None)
```

If you make a `GET` to your view, your form will be invalid if you pass an empty `request.POST`, so you need to pass `None` instead.

Lastly, I'd recommend adding `api_response = None` in your `else` clause.  This will prevent api_response from ever being undefined, and your server won't give a 500 error if someone is tampering with the form.

Comment: So simple! Knew it was a silly mistake. Thank you so much :) Have a good day